# Is there a shorter code for the following simple file manipulation program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is the problem and i have  written the code.Can someone have the answer code shortened?

> Suppose the file studentdata.txt contains information on grades students earned on various
>   assignments. Each line has the last name of a student (which you can assume is one word) and
>   the numeric grade that student received. All grades are out of 100 points. Students can appear
>   multiple times in the file.
>   Here’s a sample file:

```
Arnold 90
Brown 84
Arnold 80
Cocher 77
Cocher 100
```

Write a function that reads the data from the file into a dictionary. Then continue prompting the
user for names of students. For each student, it should print the average of that student’s grades.
Stop prompting when the user enters the name of a student not in the dictionary.
A sample run for the given file:

```
Enter name: Arnold
The average for Arnold is: 85.0 
Enter name: Brown
The average for Brown is: 84.0
Enter name: Cocher
The average for Cocher is: 88.5
Enter name: Doherty
Goodbye!
```

Here is my code :

```
import os
PATH="C:/Users/user/Desktop/studentdata.txt"
fd=open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/studentdata.txt","r")

d=fd.read()
p1=r"\b[A-za-z]+\b"
p2=r"\b[0-9]+\b"
l1=re.findall(p1,d) 
fd=open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/studentdata.txt","r")
l2=re.findall(p2,d)
d={}
for key,val in list(zip(l1,l2)):
    if key not in d:
        d[str(key)]=int(val)
    else:
        d[str(key)]+=int(val)
for key in d:
    d[key]=d[key]/l1.count(key)


while True:
    key=input("Enter name:")
    if key not in d:
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    print("the average for "+key+" is: "+str(d[key]))
```

Comment: This is a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To answer your question, yes, this can be shortened. Read up on `with` statements and `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: ... and [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

Comment: i have seen many one liner code.i wondered if that could be possible

Comment: No matter how cool one-liners are, you really don't want a full program to be one.

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions if a simple `split` is enough.

Comment: Opening a file can be done in half the number of lines than your 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PATH = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/"
FILE = "studentdata.txt"
with open(PATH + FILE, 'r') as fp:
  lines = fp.readlines()
notes_with_students = {}

for line in lines:
  student = line.split()[0]
  note = line.split()[1]
  if student not in notes_with_students:
    notes_with_students.setdefault(student, [int(note), 1])
  else:
    notes_with_students[student][0] += int(note)
    notes_with_students[student][1] += 1

while True:
  student = input("Enter name: ")
  if student not in notes_with_students:
    print("Goodbye!")
    break
  print("The average for {} is: {}".format(student, notes_with_students[student][0]/notes_with_students[student][1]))
```

This can be useful.

Comment: Parts of this are useful, but it doesn't work: it doesn't handle repeat names and it doesn't take the average. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [answer].

Comment: @wjandrea I had not read the entire problem, sorry for this misunderstanding. I fixed the code. Also thanks for your welcome.

Comment: That's closer, but still not fixed. The question has the expected output, yours should match that.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with output. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Well have you actually tried running it? Arnold's average should be 85, but your code says 45.

Comment: My apologies, i forgot a line. This time I definitely fixed it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing. You could simplify that by making `notes_with_students[student]` a list of scores, then getting its `len` later, or better yet use `statistics.mean`.